# How to run script in v-html

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I get embed codes (Instagram, Twitter and so on) from database. How to bind them to a vue component? Is there any way for executing script tag in v-html?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: You can't. Your browsers blocks the execution of script tags once the dom has loaded.

Long answer: You could try matching the src attribute of the script and fetch + evaluate it, or match the inner content of the div and evaluate it, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for answer! As I understood v-html use innerHTML, which don't execute script tag. But there are some workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: This is the eval solution, which needs to you match the inner content of a script. 
I still strongly recommend you to avoid using this workaround and find a better solution instead

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of the title, the browser will block you.

However, for the purpose of the question, you can easily predict/list the embed codes you want to support, so this is something you could do:

```js
if (window.twttr) {
  // The script is already loaded, so just reload the embeds
  window.twttr.widgets.load();
} else if (!document.getElementByID('twttr-widgets')) {
  const embed = document.createElement('script');
  embed.id = 'twttr-widgets'
  embed.src = 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
  document.body.appendChild(embed);
  // And when the script loads, the embeds will load too
}
```

This can easily be replicated for most embed libraries that allow you to "reload" all the widgets on the page:

- [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) `FB.XFBML.parse`
- [Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/javascript-api/guides/scripting-loading-and-initialization) `twttr.widgets.load`
- [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/) `instgrm.Embeds.process`